# Squish not recording keypress events for mapped keys in Qt Application

Tags: qt, automated-tests, squish

I am testing the Squish software for automated testing and trying to record test cases. I have an application that has mapped several of the keys to perform certain tasks within the application like `PgDn` moves focus clockwise or `[` moves a small screen element up. When I click the record button in squish, it only records keypress events for keys that are not mapped - severely limiting my test case creation capability. The only thing I found was two comments from 3+ years ago [here](https://www.froglogic.com/blog/squish-tip-of-the-week-how-to-execute-keyboard-and-mouse-combination-commands/) with no response or resolution. When I watch the sponsored tutorials, every keypress is captured in their resulting script. Has anyone experienced this and found a workaround?

Comment: Key presses should generally be recorded. However, sometimes Squish cannot decide what to record, the key press or the effect of the same (Alt+F4 -> type(..., "<Alt+F4>") or closeWindow() or similar)? I recommend to contact the vendor to have the specific case investigated. However, please note that you are not limited to what is being recorded, you can actually add commands to Squish test scripts yourself, such as type(), etc. If you use recorded commands as template for such action (like type() with an unmapped key), it should be fairly easy.

Comment: @frog.ca I did contact the vendor and got it cleared up - at least enough for us to move forward. For creating the test cases, i have found that both `type()` and `nativeType()` have met my needs. I think the issue has to do with QEvent filters that we have in place independent of Squish hooks.